Serialize a java enum with multiple values
Here is a simplified version of the actual problem.
I have an enum with each entry having multiple properties
 enum MyEntries{
    ENTRY1("1","property1"),
    ENTRY2("2","property2"),
    ENTRY3("3","property3");

    private String code;
    private String someProperty

    public MyEntries (String code,String someProperty){
        this.code=code;
        this.someProperty=someProperty;
   }
}

I want this endpoint to return a list of all MyEntries, with their code & someProperty values
@RestController 
class MyController{

  @GetMapping
   public List<MyEntries> getcall(){
       return MyEntries.values();
   }

  @PostMapping
   public List<MyEntries> postcall(List<MyEntries>){
       return MyEntries.values();
   }

}

Current output
[
ENTRY1,
ENTRY2,
ENTRY3
]

Required output
       [          
        {"code":"1","someProperty":"property1"},               
        {"code":"2","someProperty":"property2"},          
        {"code":"3","someProperty":"property3"}        
       ]

I am able to make w post call work by
adding @JsonProperty on both properties
creating following @JsonCreator  in enum
@JsonCreator
public static MyEntries fromValue(@JsonProperty("code") String a,
@JsonProperty("someProperty") String b) {

     for (MyEntries entry : MyEntries.values()) {

        if (entry.code.equals(a) && entry.someProperty.equals(b)) {
             return entry;
         }
        }
     return null;
}

but I am unable to receive same response in my Get call

You can use the @JsonValue annotation to define a method on your enum that will return a transport object containing the internal state of the enumeration element.
public enum Color {

    RED(1, "red"),
    GREEN(2, "green"),
    BLUE(3, "blue");

    private int id;
    private String name;

    Color(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public Value getValue() {
        return new Value(id, name);
    }

    public record Value(int id, String name) {
    }
}

For more information, see Jackson Annotation Examples.
